# Where is httpd.conf?

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu

I want to deploy a django app on an Ubuntu machine.

I installed apache2:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Next, I have to edit httpd.conf (I'm reading [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)) but I don't know where it is.

Where is httpd.conf?

Comment: You don't use the main conf file on Debian/Ubuntu systems. You define your own host-specific file in /etc/apache2/sites-available. See for example https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Ubuntu and Debian

The configuration file will be in `/etc/apache2/`

According to the [answer on another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/652100), the file might also be named `apache2.conf`.

## CentOS

The file will be in `/etc/httpd/`

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu and debian

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Centos and redhat

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```